# WPF, nothing shows up in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, itemssource

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.  I have a `ListBox` whose `DataContext` and `ItemsSource` are set, but there is nothing in the `ListBox` when I run my app.  When debugging, the first line of my method for getting items for the `ListBox` never gets hit.  Here's what I have:

```
// Constructor in UserControl
public TemplateList()
{
    _templates = new Templates();
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}

// ItemsSource of ListBox
public List<Template> GetTemplates()
{
    if (!tryReadTemplatesIfNecessary(ref _templates))
    {
        return new List<Template>
            {
                // Template with Name property set:
                new Template("No saved templates", null)
            };
    }
    return _templates.ToList();
}
```

Here's my XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetTemplates}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
         Width="400" Height="300" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
         SelectedValuePath="Name"/>
```

On an instance of the `Template` class, there's a `Name` property that is just a `string`.  All I want is to display a list of template names.  The user won't change any data in a `Template`, the `ListBox` just needs to be read-only.

A Template also has a `Data` property that I will later display in this `ListBox`, so I don't want to make `GetTemplates` return just a list of strings--it needs to return some collection of `Template` objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't bind to a method. Make it a property and it should work.

Its better though to set the List as DataContext, or create a ViewModel that holds the list. Thay way, you will have more control over the instances your Listbox will bind to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is much cleaner!  I made my `GetTemplates` method private and set `DataContext = GetTemplates()` in the constructor.  Then I just set `ItemsSource` in my XAML to the `List` property my `Templates` class already had--thanks!

Comment: BTW if you really wish to call a method from Xaml, take a look at the ObjectDataProvider. Bea Stollnitz has a nice blog about it:

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=22

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to call a method in your binding when you should be using a property. Change it to a property and you should be good to go.

```
public List<Template> MyTemplates {get; private set;}

public TemplateList()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetTemplates();
    DataContext = this;
}

// ItemsSource of ListBox
public void SetTemplates()
{
    // do stuff to set up the MyTemplates proeprty
    MyTemplates = something.ToList();
}
```

Xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyTemplates}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
   Width="400" Height="300" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
   SelectedValuePath="Name"/>
```